# matching the meaning of word from customized dictionary

Tags: php, dictionary, customization

I'm building a simple application that will match the meaning of the word with customized dictionary (in Malay word).

The words are : **saya suka makan nasi ayam dan minum laici** 
the meaning in English are (in Malay): I like to eat chicken rice and drink lychee.

My question is, how to match the word "saya suka makan nasi ayam dan minum laici " with the meaning in the customized dictionary?

The **sample output :**

```
saya : i suka : like makan : to_eat nasi : rice ayam : chicken dan : 
and minum : to_drink laici : lychee.
```

The image shown is the word and the meaning. 
[image: the image shown is the word and the meaning[1].

Comment: You explained what you are trying to do, but it's unclear what your question is

Comment: Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I'm sorry for giving such a bad explanation. My question is, how to match the word "saya suka makan nasi ayam dan minum laici " with the meaning in the customized dictionary?

Comment: Can you update the question with your explanation?

Comment: i already update the question. Thank you for your concern

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all store all your words in an array like below

```
$words=array('ayam'=>'chicken','dan'=>'and','laici'=>'lychee','makan'=>'to_eat','minum'=>'to_drink','nasi'=>'rice','saya'=>'i','suka'=>'like');
```

Then prepare string like below and then print it

```
$stringToPrint=$words['saya'].' '.$words['suka'].' '.$words['makan'].' '.$words['nasi'].' '.$words['ayam'].' '.$words['dan'].' '.$words['minum'].' '.$words['laici'];

echo $stringToPrint;
```